# Django- Staying DRY with multiple model methods

Tags: django, django-models

What's the preferred way to stay DRY when using model methods that require the results of another model method?

For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    c = models.IntegerField()

def _method_one(self):
    x = a + b    
    return x    
    method_one = property(_method_one)

def _method_two(self):
    x = a + b
    y = x + c
    return y
    method_two = property(_method_two)

def _method_three(self):
    x = a + b
    y = x + c
    z = x + y
    return z
    method_three = property(_method_three)
```

As more and more methods rely on the solutions of previous ones, I end up with repeating code. What's the cleanest way to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    b = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    c = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.a + self.b

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.x + self.c

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.x + self.y
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that early on but for some reason it didn't work for me. I must have been doing something wrong, but this is working like I'd expect.

Comment: The defaults on the fields are important, otherwise you'll get errors. Always code defensively, even against yourself :)

Comment: Good to know! I will start implementing them on my models. Thanks for your help!